# Python, decimal figures, complex numbers

Tags: python, cubic

I am currently writing a program to determine the roots of a cubic equation. This is what I have written so far:

```
import math
def sols(a, b, c, d ):
    disc = 18*a*b*c*d - 4*(b**3)*d + (b**2)*(c**2) - 4*a*(c**3) - 27*(a**2)*(d**2)
    x = b**2.0 - 3.0*a*c
    y = 2.0*(b**3.0) - 9.0*a*b*c + 27.0*(a**2.0)*d
    alpha = complex(-0.5, 0.5*math.sqrt(3))
    if disc >= 0:
        C = ((y + complex (0, math.sqrt (27.*(a**2)*disc)))/2)**(1.0/3)
        sol1 = -(1/3*a)*(b + C + x/C)
        sol2 = -(1/3*a)*(b + C*alpha + x/(C*alpha))
        sol3 = -(1/3*a)*(b + C*(alpha**2)) + x/(C*(alpha**2))
```

a, b, c, d are real. If the discriminant is bigger than zero I should be left with three real roots. C computes a number that is complex, however whenever C is used in sol1 the complex parts should cancel each other and I should be left with a real solution.

Given the values a=2, b=3, c=-11 d=-6 I obtain for C and x/C:

```
In[11]: C
Out[12]: (7.5+4.330127018922192j)
In[13]: x/C
Out[14]: (7.500000000000002-4.330127018922193j)
```

As I said before the two complex parts should cancel, and the do up until their very last decimal figure. So instead of C - x/C = 15, I get:

```
In[26]: C + x/C
Out[27]: (15.000000000000002-8.881784197001252e-16j)
```

I don't understand how to fix this. I dont know what is wrong with my program that makes my values of C and x/C differ by one decimal figure. Please can someone offer any form of help!!!

Comment: `(15.000000000000002-8.881784197001252e-16j)` _is_ 15. That `-8.8e-16j` is so close to zero it is within floating point precision.

Comment: @tobias_k thank you for your edits, apologies as I am new to the forum.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is inexact. Values that should cancel out to zero rarely do. (In fact, you can almost rely on them not canceling exactly.) You can test whether the discriminant is positive and, if so, zero out the imaginary parts of the solutions before returning the roots. (It would be reasonable to first check that the imaginary part is indeed small.)

Comment: @TedHopp I apologise for having to ask what is probably a basic question, however I am very much a beginner when it comes to programming. Could you direct me on how to zero out the imaginary part as you are suggesting?

Comment: As you probably see now, discrepancies like this are inevitable. The typical way of dealing with them in computer code is to provide a parameter in the a function such as yours that indicates the degree of tolerance to allow in various calculations, in this case the discriminant. You would compare the tolerance value (say 10**(-6)) against the *modulus* of the discrimant.

Comment: I'm not a Python programmer, but I believe that if `z` is a complex number, then you can zero out the imaginary part with `z.imag = 0`. At worse, you'd have to do something like `z = complex(z.real, 0)`.